# Installing R packages in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, r, ssms

I'm currently trying to run a R-script in SSMS 2016. I log on to a server (via remote desktop) to run SSMS, and in SSMS I connect to yet another SQL server. I believe this is what causes my error: When I try to install a R package such as dplyr, I get a message saying that the path is not writeable. I figure this could be because I'm on a server.

My script looks like:
    lib.SQL <- "//...//..."
    install.packages("dplyr", lib = lib.SQL)

The error I get looks like:

> Error in install.packages("dplyr", lib = lib.SQL) :   'lib =
>   "//...//..."' is not writable

I have tried both using the standard path (i.e. not defining a new lib.SQL), using both //, /, \, and \ defining the path, and I have tried define a path that I know I have privileges to read/write from.

Also, if I don't install any packages I can load data into R, manipulate the data and put it back into a table on the SQL server, all from SSMS, so I think R in SSMS is working in general on my setup. Furthermore, running my script in R Studio on the remote desktop installing new packages works just fine.

Does anybody have any kind of idea as of how to solve the issue? Any help is much appreciated!